# cacert ssl certificate for servers hosting secure facebook applications

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, digital-certificate

I want to install the cacert ssl certificate on a server on which i want to host secure (https) facebook applications .I want to know if facebook allows https server to have cacert certificate to fetch facebook app

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as you have a valid browser cert you will be fine. I have specifically used GoDaddy's ca certificate chain with a secure Facebook app with no difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

For the majority of cheap shared hosting environments you don't necessarily need to purchase individual ssl as long as the server has a shared SSL as discussed [here](http://scalingexcellence.co.uk/secure-facebook-ssl-hosting).